# SESSION in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
 $session = array('name' =>'chapter'); 
 $this->session->set_userdata($session);  
 $sess =  $this->session->userdata('name');
```

This is my session & this is not able to go in another method of same class why?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. The `$session` variable is local in which method you declare. You have to load `Session` if not already in the controller.

Now to set Session:

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('your_variable_name', $session);
```

to get data:

```
$sess =  $this->session->userdata('your_variable_name');
```

Comment: when I am retrieving session value in the another method of class I am getting  themes ,index.html ,plugins why?

Comment: what do you set in session data? what you get? put the values.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load `SESSION` library in your controller, use the syntax below:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

then only `set_userdata` and `userdata` will work.

To set data for session:-

```
$session = array(
                   'name'  => 'chapter',
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($session);
```

for retrieving Session Data:-

```
$this->session->userdata('name');
```

Comment: I HAVE ALREADY DONE THIS BUT MY SESSION IS NOT WORKING